# Remove black background in dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm seeing the black background in Api 8 emulator, how to remove this?

This is the dialog creation code,

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

    //Dialog alert = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Light_Panel);

    // Build the dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    //alert.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglayout, null));

    alert.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglayout, null));

    alert.setTitle("Testing title");

    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 

    alert.setCancelable(false);


    alert.show();
```

This is how dialog looks

[image]

MY layout code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@color/WHITE" >

<ScrollView
    android:id = "@+id/id_scroll_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@color/WHITE" >



    <View
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/id_prim_separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@color/GRAY"/>


     <TextView 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop ="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/BLUE"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/id_prim_separator"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/ID_title"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="This is sample Title"
        />


     <TextView 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ID_snooze_task_description"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ID_title"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/DARKGRAY"
        android:text="This is sample description"
        />


         <View
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ID_snooze_task_description"
    android:id="@+id/id_details_separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@color/GRAY"/>



    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     android:id="@+id/id_preview_button"
     android:layout_below="@+id/id_scroll_view"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id = "@+id/id_edit_btn"
               android:text="Edit"
            />


        <Button 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id = "@+id/id_ok_btn"
               android:text="Ok"
            />


        <Button 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id = "@+id/id_cancel_btn"
               android:text="Cancel"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `AlertDialog` I think you should use `Dialog` or depending on your applications hierarchy `DialogFragment`. Using `Dialog` you can achieve the desired result like this :

```
Dialog alert = new Dialog(MyAcivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Light_Panel);
alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
alert.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null));
alert.show();
```

Comment: But, i cant have icon while displaying title, some constraints it has, so i thought of going by alertdialog. Dialog requires more customizations.

Comment: You need to put desired icon in your xml as ImageView.

Comment: Oh, yes i will try that option, perhaps it may solve my problem. Thank u. ill try and let u know.

Comment: Or a better option, you can use TextView with `android:drawableLeft` option. This is better way instead of using TextView and ImageView.

Comment: thank you for your quick tip,ill check it, +1 for your tip & answer . Thanks